# How to create an identical copy of a tree and store it in a map in Go

Tags: go, pointers, tree

I have a tree structure, where any node can have multiple children, but only one parent. The nodes are connected by pointers and I would like to store this hierarchy in a map, where I can quickly access children and root nodes.

I currently have a version that can carry out the desired behaviour, but it stores the addresses of the inputs in the map. So if any of the items in the map are updated, it updates the original hierarchy as well, which I would like to avoid. So, I would like to store an exact copy of my hierarchy in the map, that has the same structure, but is not connected to the original one in any way. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

[playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/vgvYnixSK4p)

```
type node struct {
value    string
children []*node
parent   *node
}

// isRoot returns true if node is a root
func (node *node) isRoot() bool {
    return node.parent == nil
}

var rootMap = make(map[string]*node)
var childrenMap = make(map[string]*node)

func main() {
    /*
          A
          |
          B
        /   \
       C     D
    */

    a := node{value: "a"}
    b := node{value: "b", parent: &a}
    c := node{value: "c", parent: &b}
    d := node{value: "d", parent: &b}

    a.children = []*node{&b}
    b.children = []*node{&c, &d}

    storeHierarchy(&a)

    mappedA, _ := rootMap[a.value]
    mappedB, _ := childrenMap[b.value]

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("mappedA: %p, a: %p - not equal, which is perfect", mappedA, &a))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("mappedB: %p, a: %p - not equal, which is perfect", mappedB, &b))

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("mappedA.child[0]: %p, a.child[0]: %p - these are equal, but should not be", mappedA.children[0], a.children[0]))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("mappedA.child[0]: %p, first child b: %p - these are not equal, but should be", mappedA.children[0], mappedB))
}

func storeHierarchy(order *node) {
    orderCopy := *order
    order = &orderCopy

    for i := range order.children {
        child := order.children[i]
        storeHierarchy(child)
    }

    if order.isRoot() {
        rootMap[order.value] = order
    } else {
        childrenMap[order.value] = order
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code makes a copy of nodes, which includes copying the `children` field which is a slice header to children. But you never change elements in `children`, so they will be the same. Also note that a deep copy would also have to clone the slice, as assigning a slice header will point to the same backing array. Also, you don't change the `parent` fields of the copied nodes, so those will point to the original nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Let me try to fix the issues that you have mentioned.